# Python 2.7, Multiprocessing and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to create a class that launches a tkinter form from a new instance of python using multiprocessing.

My question is this: What would be the recommended way of passing the Tkinter class object to the multiprocessing function?  When I normally pass objects to the multiprocessing pool, I have to convert the objects to string.  Does this mean I have to pickle the class?  Is there a better way to do this?

I cannot using threading because some of the python packages I have to use are not thread safe.. :(

Sample Code:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

########################################################################
class TkinterApp(object):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""

        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("Main frame")
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        btn = Tk.Button(self.frame, text="Close Frame", command=self.hide)
        btn.pack()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def hide(self):
        """"""
        self.root.withdraw()
```

System Specs:

- Windows 7
- Python 2.7.5 32-bit

Any suggestions or feedback is very welcome!

Thank you

Comment: You can't pass widgets across a process boundary.

Comment: That stinks.  There goes my idea.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered any problems creating the Tkinter instance outside of the pool, and the class instance as well, and then calling the functions from separate processes.  A "simple" example is below

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

try:
    import Tkinter as tk    ## Python 2.x
except:
    import tkinter as tk    ## Python 3.x

class ProgressBar():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("75x50+900+100")
        self.ctr=25

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_countdown(self):
        """ a separate process in a separate GUI
        """
        self.root.withdraw()
        self.top_count=tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.top_count.geometry("75x50+750+50")
        self.label_ctr = tk.IntVar()
        self.label_ctr.set(self.ctr)
        label = tk.Label(self.top_count, textvariable=self.label_ctr)
        label.pack()
        if self.ctr > 0:
            self.top_count.after(750, self.update)

    def start_running(self):
        """ create the progress bar widget
        """
        self.top=tk.Toplevel(self.root, takefocus=True)
        self.top.title("Progress Bar")
        self.top.geometry("+700+200")
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.top, width=261, height=60, bg='lightgray')
        canvas.pack()

        rc2 = canvas.create_rectangle(15, 20, 243, 50, outline='blue', \
                                      fill='lightblue')
        rc1 = canvas.create_rectangle(24, 20, 34, 50, outline='white', \
                                      fill='blue')

        total=100
        x = 5
        while self.ctr:        ## move the small rectangle +5 or -5 units
            total += x
            if total > 311:
                x = -5
            elif total < 100:
                x = 5
            time.sleep(0.2)
            canvas.move(rc1, x, 0)
            canvas.update()

    def update(self):
        self.ctr -= 1
        self.label_ctr.set(self.ctr)

        if self.ctr > 0:
            self.top_count.after(750, self.update)
        else:
            ## sleep to allow any remaining after() to execute
            ## can also use self.root.after_cancel(id)
            self.top_count.after(500, self.root.destroy) ## destroy root when zero is reached

root = tk.Tk()

PB=ProgressBar(root)
pr1=Process(target=PB.start_countdown(), args=())
pr1.start()

pr2=Process(target=PB.start_running(), args=())
pr2.start()

## start mainloop in a separate process as a function of the class
## don't know if this is really necessary or not
## the theory is, it is detached from the other 2 processes and so
##    can react to both independently
## also the mainloop() process can be killed=shut down properly
pr3=Process(target=PB.mainloop(), args=())
pr3.start()

## safety clean up
pr1.terminate()
pr2.terminate()
pr3.terminate()
```

Comment: I'll give it shot, thank you.  For the root object, tk.Tk(), should that be called on the new process or does it not matter?

Comment: In this case it does not matter because it is a class attribute and both functions are members of the class.  I would think that you could also pass it to the function that is called, but have not tested that in complex programs.  In any case you do not want more than one Tk() instance, but can use many Toplevels and pass it to the function as well.

Comment: I'm missing something or this code (`pr1=Process(target=PB.start_countdown(), args=())`) does not doing what you want: `PB.start_countdown()` returns `None`.

Comment: You don't even need `Process` in this code! You don't actually fork anything! You can replace everything after class definition with

    `root = tk.Tk()`
    
    `PB = ProgressBar(root)`
    `PB.start_countdown()`
    `PB.start_running()`

(even no PB.mainloop() is needed!)

Comment: This is a simple example on how to use multiprocessing and Tkinter together, to be adapted to a more complex problem.  And yes, the function PB.start_countdown() was programmed so it doesn't return anything (None).