# How can I move two tkinter widgets simultaneously but asynchronous?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing, tkinter-canvas

Question is straight forward. Is there any way I can canvas.move image A to the right at the same time as I canvas.move image B to the left?

I've achieved this before by using multiprocessing to run multiple canvases layered over it, but it's very much a workaround I've made up.

Is there any official/better way to do this? Any suggestion helps.

Comment: Well, yes. A simple function would do the job. Or you may consider `tag_bind`? I think you should review your question if there is all of the information thats needed to solve your question. Its not clear to me why you need our help.

Comment: A simple function like what? Tag_bind how? I thought I was pretty explicit, it's also not a bug or anything more of a question of how I would go about it. I've avoided moving with tags because as far as I know that eould move them simultaneously but also synchronously, i.e. canvas.move(tag, amount) when they both have the tag moves them the same amount and direction.

Comment: What have you tried so far.

Comment: Like I said, I've tried layering canvases by making the top canvases transparent and multiprocessing. This works, but it's very janky so I was wondering if there was another way. I did some more research and I'm going to attempt multiprocessing in a different way by making a Toplevel or canvas.create_window for each object like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233208/python-2-7-multiprocessing-and-tkinter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do. Just call the `move` method for the two objects at the same time. When the screen updates, both will be updated simultaneously.

For example, the following code will move each image 5 pixels every time you press the space key on your keyboard:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="black", width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

image_a = tk.PhotoImage(width=50, height=50)
image_b = tk.PhotoImage(width=50, height=50)
image_a.put(("#ff0000",), (0, 0, 49, 49))
image_b.put(("#00ff00",), (0, 0, 49, 49))

canvas.create_image(175, 200, image=image_a, tags=("image_a",))
canvas.create_image(225, 200, image=image_b, tags=("image_b",))

def sync_move(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    canvas.move("image_a", 5, 0)
    canvas.move("image_b", -5, 0)

canvas.bind("<space>", sync_move)
canvas.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: to my knowledge this will not work as intended. For two moving once, sure, but they do not execute simultaneously, just in quick succession. I encourage you to try this with many objects, eventually you will notice a difference from the first move to the last. You can also see the difference if you try it in a recursion loop; they will move much slower when they are moving 'at the same time' because they actually aren't, they're just both being moved before the recursion loop restarts

Comment: @Matt: you didn't specify any requirements, so I have no idea what "as intended" means.  I tried it with 500 pairs of images and it works fine. If you have specific constraints you need to work in, you should specify that in the question. If you're trying to animate thousands or tens of thousands of images, tkinter is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: that's very fair. I'm not attempting to animate thousands. If it truly works for 500 images I will test your answer, if results are good you have my apologies and thanks

Comment: Okay so apparently I'm a very stupid and stubborn person that's been making things waayyyyy harder for myself for way over a year. I had previously tried running canvas.move twice in a row in a mainloop and noticed significant difference in speed, but I now think that was likely due to other issues. Thank you for your patience in dealing with my stupidity

Comment: @Matt this happens. I do this like 10 times in a 500 lines code till I get it and shrink the code to 200. Happy coding. :D

Comment: It's always a good day when you can improve the code by removing a few lines.

Comment: Yes sir. Thanks guys! Made my life a lot easier for the next few months.